# What's *the* modern way not to duplicate code on HTML pages and subpages?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, ruby-on-rails

So I'm making a HTML(5) page that will link to a couple of subpages.

I have a navigation menu and a footer that are quite elaborate CSS and HTML -wise. Copypasting  this code for every subpage is an option but I suspect there's a better way.

Back in the day it was most often accomplished using frames, but they are now quite *passe*.

I didn't find a 'default' go-to solution anywhere... The suggestions are:

Use Javascript to *document.write* the code on subpages. **OR**
Use PHP to generate the site so that navigation and footer are included from a separate file **OR**
Use Ruby on Rails (would have to grasp it to a decent extent... and I'm not sure if this is even the sort of thing it's used for)

What's the best way? Isn't PHP an overkill for a fairly simple site? (yeah it has navigation etc. but otherwise it's pretty simple). Any other suggestions?

Comment: PHP is about as little overkill as you can get for what you want.

Comment: Are you aware that "ruby on rails" is **not** a programming language?

Comment: If you are referring to the fact that it is a programming environment then I'm aware of that. If Ruby in general is not used in web development in a relevant way then sorry, I wasn't aware of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IF your server has PhP functionlity, it is probably the easiest way to go.

```
<?php
require("header.php");
?>
```

is all you need to do in order to include the full header section into a new page.

I would not got the javascript route, as you will be only loading the javascript once the page is starting to load. That means the page starts to load, and then needs to get additional info from the server. Also, server-side is more reliable.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I was looking for. PHP it is!

Answer (score 0):

Server Side Includes are probably the easiest way:

```
<!--#include virtual="header.html" -->

    some html

<!--#include virtual="footer.html" -->
```

Links:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/ssi.html

Comment: That's certainly interesting. For this project I'd much rather go with something I already - sort of - know but I'll surely have a look into Server Side Includes.

Answer (score -1):

My own website is using `include("XXX.php")` or `require(xxx.php)` to include the header, footer and common codes. I think it's quite an easy-understanding and simple way to implement such function. 
like this:

```
...
///below is header
<?php include("header.php"); ?>
/// header ends
...
```

Also you can create such separate html files and using JS to render them into your page, and this does not require php environment.Like:

```
<div id="header"></div>
<script>
$( "#header" ).load( "commom/header.html" );
</script>
```

and save your header code into "header.html" file.